# Django Contact Form Attachment showing 'This field is required.' What am I doing Wrong?

Tags: python, django

Views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage,send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm


def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            image1 = request.FILES['image1']
            full_message = str([from_email,name.upper(), phone, message])

            try:
                email =    EmailMessage(subject.upper(),full_message,from_email+'<sender@gmail.com>',['pratirup8@gmail.com'],headers = {'Reply-To': from_email })
                email.attach(image1.name, image1.read(), image1.content_type)
                email.send()
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})


def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
     name = forms.CharField(required=True)
     phone = forms.CharField(required=True)
     from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
     subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
     message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
     image1 = forms.Field(label='sample photo', widget = forms.FileInput, required = True )
```

If I send the mail with out attachment its working but when i add an attachment file it shows "This field is required." in the webpage[this image is a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Lx2.png) i want to know what am doing wrong and how can i send and mail with the attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass FILES into the form as well, since it has a file field:

```
    form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

This is all explained in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) for uploading files.

Comment: 'image1 = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES['image1'])' like this ?

Comment: tried to put " form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)" in  form = ContactForm() doesnt work same "This Field Required" showing up

Comment: Are you using the enctype on the form element int the tempate, again as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads)?

Comment: Thank You So much It worked :) really thnx i am a noob in django thank you for you patience too :)